# swift Encodable override encode with 2 different dateformats

Tags: swift, codable

I have class conforming to Encodable which contains 2 date properties.
When I'm encoding it to string I'd like these 2 dates to use different date formatting -
for example

> Optional("{\n  "date1" : "2022-10-24T22:03:43Z",\n  "date2" : 688342014.16646099\n}")

but I cant figure out how to do it, heres example code

```
  func getString() -> String? {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    
    guard let data = try? encoder.encode(TwoDates()) else { return nil }
    guard let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
    return dataString
  }
class TwoDates: Encodable {
  public var date1 = Date()
  public var date2 = Date()
  
  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try? container.encode(date1, forKey: .date1)
    try? container.encode(date1, forKey: .date2)
  }
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case date1 = "date1"
    case date2 = "date2"
  }
}
```

So, how to use different date formatters for 2 different properties? Should I somehow override JSONEncoder.encode()?

Comment: Have you looked into [`JSONEncoder.DateEncodingStrategy.custom`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/dateencodingstrategy/custom) Right now you're using an ISO 8601 encoder unconditionally, but with the `.custom` strategy you can use a different format based on the encoder's `codingPath`, which allows you to pick per property

Comment: Alternatively, if you're already implementing `encode(to:)` yourself, you can format each property separately before encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You're already encoding a date object; sounds like what you want is to decode into separate formats. For that just override your decode and use DateFormatter() objects. You can find docs and examples here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter
If you want to archive as another object you could use the formatter in encode override. Keep in mind the payload will be larger that way though.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually so simple I cant believe it, just need to provide dateformat on encoding, i.e

```
    try? container.encode(date1.iso8601String, forKey: .date1)
```